# How to transform text area to link?

Tags: javascript, html

Here is my code snippet:

```js
  function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
    }
```

```html
 <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
 <body>
 <textarea id="myTextarea"></textarea>
 <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Transform into link</button>
 <a href="" target="_blank" id="demo"></a>
    <script src="links.js"></script>
 </body>
 </html>
```

Somehow, the created link is not opened when I click on it. Kind of stuck at this point.

Comment: As far as I can see the href attribute of the link remains empty so it isn't linking to anything. You only define the innerHTML of the anchor element.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You were doing it right, you just needed to use href instead of innerHTML.

```js
function myFunction() {
    var x = document.getElementById("myTextarea").value;
    document.getElementById("demo").href = x;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <textarea id="myTextarea"></textarea>
        <button type="button" onclick="myFunction()">Transform into link</button>
        <a href="" target="_blank" id="demo">My Link!</a>
        <script src="links.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```